# php content encoding fail while importing facebook.php

Tags: php, html, encoding

I just set my page encoding to utf-8 using meta tag in html and then starting php tags , including facebook.php at first.

but at runtime, it gives me warning , that headers are already sent...

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sending output to the browser before your headers are being sent, likely a result of starting a session.

Make sure all output comes after headers are sent.

Comment: no , no output before headers ,
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
include("config.php");
...... ?>

Comment: You definitely have output somewhere. This can include hidden characters and/or spaces.

Comment: Try using the headers_sent() function to find out if / where output is being started.